# There is no route defined for key auths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm working on an application where i'm using `react-native-router-flux` for navigation but getting this error

[image]

Here's my Router

```
<Router navTransparent>
            <Lightbox>
                <Scene key="root" tintColor="#fff" style={{position: 'absolute'}} hideNavBar>
                    <Scene key="redirect" component={EnsureAuthentication}/>
                    <Scene key="auth" navBar={CustomNavBar}>
                        <Scene key="loginSignUp" component={Login} hideNavBar/>
                        <Scene key="login" component={LoginForm} title={I18n.t('loginTitle')} />
                        <Scene key="signUp" component={SignUpForm} title={I18n.t('signUpTitle')}/>
                        <Scene key="googleLogin" component={GoogleLogin}/>
                    </Scene>
                    <Drawer hideNavBar key="app" contentComponent={DrawerContent} drawerWidth={300} drawerOpenRoute="DrawerOpen" drawerCloseRoute="DrawerClose" drawerToggleRoute="DrawerToggle">
                        <Scene key="main" navBar={CustomNavBar}>
                            <Scene key="MapSearch" component={MapSearch}/>
                            <Scene key="ScanQr" hideNavBar component={ScanQr} />
                            <Scene key="searchList" hideNavBar component={SearchList}/>
                            <Scene key="editUserProfile" component={EditUserProfile} title={I18n.t('update')} />
                            <Scene key="stallDetails" hideNavBar component={StallDetails}/>
                            <Scene key="customise" hideNavBar component={Customise}/>
                            <Scene key="cart" hideNavBar component={Cart}/>
                            <Scene key="favourites" hideNavBar component={Favourites}/>
                        </Scene>
                    </Drawer>
                </Scene>
                <Scene key="overlay"/>
                <Scene key="orderOverlay" hideNavBar component={OrderOverlay}/>
                <Scene key="confirmOverlay" hideNavBar component={ConfirmOverlay}/>
                <Scene key="forgotPasswordOverlay" hideNavBar component={ForgotPasswordOverlay}/>
                <Scene key="forgotPwdSuccessOverlay" hideNavBar component={ForgotPwdSuccessOverlay}/>
            </Lightbox>
        </Router>
```

I'm calling `Actions.reset('auths');`

There is another strange behavior if i call `Actions.auths()` instead of `Actions.reset('auths');` & make some changes in same file where i'm calling this method, app reloads everything works well.

Comment: it seems like a typo with the declared `auth` scene key. calling `Actions.auth()` should direct you to the particular scene. also, have you consider passing `reset` as a `type` prop?

Comment: @kenmistry `Action.auth()` does work but in that case if i make any change in the same file and save it and the application reloads & works fine but normally it doesn't work the application stuck. `have you consider passing reset as a type prop?` how to do that? sorry to ask but I'm quite new to react-native.

Comment: what do you mean by "normally" and "the application stuck"? sure. i share it as an answer for you to test it out.

Comment: @kenmistry Thanks for your reply. "Normally" means as app runs other side is when we change some and app reloads. "the application stuck" mean there is a splash screen which shows as soon as app runs to hide the splash there is code implemented in key `loginSignUp` Scene component which is `Login` (as you can see in my Router) where code doesn't reach due to this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is caused by a typo. the `key` value of your `Action` is not called exactly as declared in your `Scene`. calling `Action.auth()` should work as intended and resolves the error.

i can see that you are trying to reset the `Scene`. you can also do that by declaring `reset` as a prop in your `Router`. in this way, navigating to the `Scene` should trigger `reset` every time.

```
<Scene key="auth" navBar={CustomNavBar} type={ActionConst.RESET}>
```

if you are trying to set up a stack of scenes for authentication process flow, you can try setting up a stack to have the `initial` prop. i've added a code snippet here for testing:

```
<Stack key="auth" navBar={CustomNavBar} initial>
  <Scene key="loginSignUp" component={Login} hideNavBar/>
  <Scene key="login" component={LoginForm} title={I18n.t('loginTitle')} />
  <Scene key="signUp" component={SignUpForm} title={I18n.t('signUpTitle')}/>
  <Scene key="googleLogin" component={GoogleLogin}/>
</Stack>
```

Comment: It's not working with `Action.auth()` on app start it does work if i make any change in the same file where i'm invoking this method and js makes it force reload.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong. what you are telling is that you are navigating from `loginSignUp` to `auth` and this error appears. and i just realise that `auth` scene does not have a component. are you trying to set up a scene stack here? if so, can you try the above code?

Comment: Dear @kenmistry i've tried your suggested code but same situation. let me explain you more there is a key in my Router above auth `redirect ` where component is `EnsureAuthentication` in that js page there is code implemented to check wether the user is logged in. If loggedin then i'm calling `Actions.app()` else  `Actions.auth()`. After app starts no error but screen stuck in Splash screen if i call `Actions.reset('auth')` and make any change in `EnsureAuthentication` page i get error which i've stated above.

Comment: On the other side if i call `Actions.auth()` same situation screen stuck on Splash but if i make any change in `EnsureAuthentication` app reloads and code works next page `key="loginSignUp" component={Login}` gets called.